# Calculus Help Finding the Arc Length

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, arc-length

So I'm having trouble with [this problem](https://gyazo.com/269a0e995aec958b7d028e81b564c75b):

> Let $$x=\frac{y^2+2y}{8}-\ln(y+1)$$
>   Find the arclength for $0\leq y\leq 2$.

**My work**. I know the Arc length formula is $(1+ (x'^2))^{1/2}$ in this case but when I take $x'$ I get $$x' = (y/4  + 1/4 - 1/(y+1))$$ and when I square that I get something way too hectic and adding $1$ to all of that makes it even more of a mess. Am I missing something here?

Comment: $ln3+1$ comes from what Robert Z suggests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going in the right direction. However note that after squaring and adding $1$ a perfect square turns out:
$$1+(x'(y))^2=1+\left(\frac{y+1}{4}-\frac{1}{y+1}\right)^2
=\frac{(y+1)^2}{16}+\frac{1}{(y+1)^2}+\frac{1}{2}=\left(\frac{t}{4}+\frac{1}{t}\right)^2.$$
where $t=y+1$. Now integrate the square root of the right-hand side for $t$ in $(1,3)$ and you will get the result.

Comment: So what is the final result?

Comment: Thank you. I will try it now. I was just wondering, is there a method in order to figure out how to factor this into a perfect square? (completing the square doesn't work here so how did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: "completing the square doesn't work  here" why?

Comment: Wouldn't that only work in something of the form Ax^2 + bx + c? Also, I got 1 + ln(3) as the answer.

Comment: @krauser126 Use $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$. In this case $ab=\frac14$

Comment: Ahhh interesting. It makes a lot of sense when you rewrite it as [(y+1)/4]^2 + [1/(y+1)]^2 + 2(1/4) . Thanks for that. The binomials and fractions messed me up.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Yes, $ab=1/4$ and $2ab=1/2$ (the term on the right). So it works!!